# django admin override queryset to get only last records in duplicates

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset

Im trying to override a django admin model queryset so i can get only the last records in a list of duplicates. Already tried this two ways :

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def get_queryset(self, obj):
    qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(obj)
    return qs.order_by('process', '-modified_at').distinct('process')
```

Or:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   qs = super(ResponsibleStateFlowAdmin, self).get_queryset(obj)
   qs = qs.extra(where=[
            "SELECT * FROM MyModel GROUP BY process ORDER BY modified DESC"
        ])
   return qs
```

But both throw errors....i tried distinct sintax for django and fails as well, and other post i've seen here are not exactly for what i need.

I update my model :

```
class MyModel(ModelBase):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
         User, 
         verbose_name = 'Responsible',
         blank = False)
    process= models.ForeignKey(Process, verbose_name = 'Process')
```

Any idea ?, Thanks in advance !

Comment: What are the errors thrown?

Comment: The first code shows "distinct not supported", but i tried all sintaxes i've seen in other post, even marked as correct and that worked for other people

Comment: [`.distinct(*args)` only works on PostgreSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).  I'm not certain what you mean by your question though; you want to only show records which are duplicates?

Comment: Please add your model to your post and define what a duplicate exactly is.

Comment: @AdamBarnes  I updated my question including the model...what i mean with the duplicates is : lets say i got 3 records of one process, each one with a state (open, queued, closed)...i need django admin only shows the last modified ( could be any of those stated i mentioned before but i don't know which at the query moment cause the process could be in any)...and so on with the other records.

Comment: @KlausD. i updated the model, please read the comment above where i explain the duplicates

Comment: Why would you have multiple records for one process with different states?  This makes it unnecessary complicated to determine which is the correct one; having to do what you're doing now with modification times.  What you should instead do is have one record per process, and update the state on it.

Comment: @AdamBarnes I know that should be the usual way...but in this case a record log with every change made in each process its necessary. That's the reason why...distinct() work only in postgre and we are using mysql, so we need a way to do it.

Comment: Then you should have a Record table with overall record data, things like the record's name, its current state, who owns it, etc., then another table, `RecordEvent`, detailing what event happened, what data you have about it, when it happened, and crucially; a `models.ForeignKey` to `Record`.